# Min & Max with Attribute in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, model, sum

I have a Product model with an attribute.

```php
public function getFinalPriceAttribute()
{
    if ($this->discount_type == 1) {
        return $this->price -= $this->discount;
    } elseif ($this->discount_type == 0) {
        return $this->price * (1 - $this->discount / 100);
    }

    return $this->price;
}
```

I need to get the min and max sum of products in Category. I can do it with:

```
$minsumm = $products->min('price');
$maxsumm = $products->max('price');
```

In the `products` collection of all products in the database. How can I get min and max price with the attribute `finalPrice?`

Comment: How are you querying the `$products`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions [`min`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-min) & [`max`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-max) allow for a closure to be passed to them. So you can do the following:

```
$minsumm = $products->min(function ($prod) { return $prod->finalPrice; });
$maxsumm = $products->max(function ($prod) { return $prod->finalPrice; });
```

Comment: Undefined property `finalPrice`

Comment: @Dumitru, you can't get an undefined property error on an Eloquent model which means you don't have a collection of models.

Comment: Can you update your question and add the code you are using to query the products?

Comment: it's $prod->finalprice; because of the mutators naming schema.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$products = Product::get();
$minPrice = $product->min('final_price');
$maxPrice = $product->max('final_price');
```

And don't forget to add $appends in your Product model

```
protected $appends = ['final_price'];
```